# JPOS Property are not self explanatory

Tags: javapos

I have a JPOS Application where the property name's are self explanatory.

```
getCapRecDhigh()
getCapRecDwide()
getCapJrnDwideDhigh()
getCapConcurrentRecSlp()
```

I am new JPOS and finding difficult to understand the terminologies.
can anyone tell me where can i get all these informations?

Comment: Hi, you are using the wrong tag. You should use `javapos`.

Answer (score 1):

you can get UnifiedPOS [pdf](https://nrf.com/resources/retail-technology-standards/unifiedpos)

For example CapRecDhigh from this pdf:

> If true, then the receipt can  print double high characters.

Comment: the current URL fir this documentation is https://www.omg.org/retail/unified-pos.htm